# Get post data from ajax post request in python file

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I'm trying to post some data with an ajax post request and execute a python file, retrieving the data in the python file, and return a result.

I have the following ajax code

```
        $(function () {
                    $("#upload").on("click", function (e) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: "test1.py",
                            data: {'param1':'abc'},
                            async: false,
                            success: function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            }
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    });
                });
```

And the following python file

```
    #! /usr/bin/python
    from __future__ import print_function
    import cgi, cgitb
    def index():
        data = cgi.FieldStorage()
        mydata = data['param1'].value
        return return "test"
```

I'm getting a keyerror on param1 -> "KeyError: 'param1'". I've also tried to use getValue(data['param1']. It looks like a problem with transferring the data from the ajax call to the python file i want to execute... But i can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't seem to get the javascript formattting right.. hmm, Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to come up with an solution. I hope other people can get use of it as well.

By the following python code i've manged to get the postdata from the ajax call.

```
    def index(req):
        postData = req.form
        json = str(postData['param'].value)
```

Comment: It's not so clear to me how `req` is defined when called in `index(req)`. Is it pointing to the data sent by the ajax call? In a separate question, I figured one can use `myDataInPython = json.load(sys.stdin)` to store that ajax data locally, and unless I use that before entering any function, the data is simply not pointed to the argument as I believe you imply. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467853/using-data-from-ajax-in-a-python-script/42528279#42528279)